# How to apply at once StringLength attribute to all properties within the class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-annotations, asp.net-core-7.0, c#-11.0

I have a class with ~400 string properties(it's auto-generated) I would like to apply         `[StringLength(50)]` to all properties within the class. Is that is possible without copy-pasting the attribute 400 times?

Comment: What is generating this code?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it using reflection, but this approach will apply the attributes at runtime, not at compile time.

```
public static void AddStringLengthAttribute(Type type, int maxLength)
{
    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var attribute = new StringLengthAttribute(maxLength);
        property.SetCustomAttribute(attribute);
    }
}
```

Then you can call `AddStringLengthAttribute(typeof(YourClass), 50);`